# При тестировании Junit + Mockito получаю ошибку HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

Я имею сущность

```
@Entity
@Table (name= "users")
public class User {

    public enum TypeShelters{
        DOG_SHELTER,
        CAT_SHELTER;

    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long chatId;
    private Integer messageId;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String name;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String location;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private User.TypeShelters typeShelter;
    private LocalDate startTrialPeriod;
    private LocalDate endTrialPeriod;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection<Pet> pets;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Collection<Report> reports;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "volunteer_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Volunteer volunteer;


    public User() {
    }

    public User(Long chatId, Integer messageId, String name, String location) {
        this.chatId = chatId;
        this.messageId = messageId;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }
  //geters and setters ...
}
```

Потом класс контроллер

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@Tag(name = "Контроллер пользователей", description = "добавление, обновление, удаление и другие операции с пользователями")
public class UserController {

    private final UserServiceInterface userService;

    public UserController(UserServiceInterface userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Operation(
            summary = "Поиск пользователя",
            description = "Позволяет найти пользователя по идентификатору",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(
                            responseCode = "200",
                            description = "Найденный пользователь"
                    )
            }
    )
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserById(@PathVariable Long id){
        User foundUser = userService.getUserById(id);
        if (foundUser == null){
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(foundUser);
    }

    @Operation(
            summary = "Добавление нового пользователя",
            description = "Позволяет добавить пользователя в базу данных"
    )
    @PostMapping(value = "/add", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        User addUser = userService.addUser(user);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(addUser);
    }
}
```

В сервисе метод по добавлению юзера в базу данных

```
@Override
    public User addUser(User user) {
        if (userRepository.existsByChatId(user.getChatId())){
            String errorMessage = "This user " + user.getName() + " already exist in DB";
            logger.error(errorMessage);
            throw new AlreadyExistException(errorMessage);
        }
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
```

И вот сам тест

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @SpyBean
    private UserServiceInterfaceImpl userService;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;

    private User user1;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    private List<User> users;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUpData() throws JSONException {
        user1 = new User();
        user1.setId(1L);
        user1.setChatId(1L);
        user1.setMessageId(1);
        user1.setName("TestName");
        user1.setLocation("Kiev");
        user1.setPhoneNumber("+380504444444");
        user1.setFirstName("Tom");
        user1.setLastName("Kook");
        user1.setEmail("tom@gmail.com");
        user1.setTypeShelter(User.TypeShelters.DOG_SHELTER);
        user1.setStartTrialPeriod(LocalDate.from(LocalDateTime.now()));
        user1.setEndTrialPeriod(LocalDate.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1)));
        user1.setVolunteer(null);

        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("id", user1.getId());
        jsonObject.put("chatId", user1.getChatId());
        jsonObject.put("messageId", user1.getMessageId());
        jsonObject.put("name", user1.getName());
        jsonObject.put("location", user1.getLocation());
        jsonObject.put("phoneNumber", user1.getPhoneNumber());
        jsonObject.put("firstName", user1.getFirstName());
        jsonObject.put("lastName", user1.getLastName());
        jsonObject.put("email", user1.getEmail());
        jsonObject.put("typeShelter", user1.getTypeShelter());
        jsonObject.put("startTrialPeriod", user1.getStartTrialPeriod());
        jsonObject.put("endTrialPeriod", user1.getEndTrialPeriod());
        jsonObject.put("volunteer", user1.getVolunteer());

        User user2 = new User();
        user2.setId(2L);
        user2.setChatId(2L);
        user2.setMessageId(2);
        user2.setPhoneNumber("+380679999999");
        user2.setFirstName("Test2");
        user2.setLastName("Last2");
        user2.setName("TestName2");
        user2.setEmail("test2@gmail.com");
        user2.setLocation("London");
        user2.setTypeShelter(User.TypeShelters.CAT_SHELTER);
        user2.setStartTrialPeriod(LocalDate.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(2)));
        user2.setEndTrialPeriod(LocalDate.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(3)));
        user2.setVolunteer(null);

        users = List.of(user1, user2);
    }

    @Test
    void createUser() throws Exception {

        when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user1);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/user/add")
                .content(jsonObject.toString())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(user1.getId()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.chatId").value(user1.getChatId()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.messageId").value(user1.getMessageId()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value(user1.getName()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.location").value(user1.getLocation()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.phoneNumber").value(user1.getPhoneNumber()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.firstName").value(user1.getFirstName()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.lastName").value(user1.getLastName()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email").value(user1.getEmail()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.typeShelter").value(user1.getTypeShelter()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.startTrialPeriod").value(user1.getStartTrialPeriod()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.endTrialPeriod").value(user1.getEndTrialPeriod()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.volunteer").value(user1.getVolunteer()));

    }
}
```

В результате выполнения получаю

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /user/add
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json", Content-Length:"249"]
             Body = {"firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Kook","endTrialPeriod":"2022-07-14","phoneNumber":"+380504444444","chatId":1,"typeShelter":"DOG_SHELTER","name":"TestName","messageId":1,"location":"Kiev","startTrialPeriod":"2022-07-13","id":1,"email":"tom@gmail.com"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = sky.pro.pet_bot.controller.UserController
           Method = sky.pro.pet_bot.controller.UserController#addUser(User)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 415
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Accept:"application/json, application/*+json"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201> but was:<415>
Expected :201
Actual   :415
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
    at sky.pro.pet_bot.UserControllerTest.createUser(UserControllerTest.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Первоначально у меня `user` сохраняется в базу с четырьмя полями имеющими какие-то значения, а остальные поля все `null`. Поэтому и тест я сначала писал только с четырьмя полями. Запустил и получил ошибку. По идее ошибка говорит, что есть несоответствие в теле запроса и в `jsonObject`, если я правильно понял. После этого я добавил все поля из класса `User`, за исключением коллекций. Но всё равно получаю эту же ошибку. Идеи у меня кончились, как это можно победить...
Подскажите, как решить данную проблему ?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в не корректном использовании аннотаций `@JsonManagedReference` и `@JsonBackReference`.
Аннотации убрал и ошибка исчезла.